# Formula for $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{i}{K - i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I find a formula for $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{i}{K - i}$, $K \in \mathbb{Z}$, $K > n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $i/(K-i)$ as $K/(K-i)-1$, one sees that this sum is also 
$$K(H_{K-1}-H_{K-n-1})-n,
$$
where $H_k=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\frac1i$ is the $k$th harmonic number. I doubt that any other general formula exists, and that this one has any practical use for fixed values of $K$ and $n$ (asymptotics being another matter).

Comment: There are potential approximations such as $K \log_e\left(1+\frac{n}{K-n-1}\right)-n$ and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2k}$.